# onFailure() not triggering on WebApplicationException in Vert.x reactive WebClient

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, mutiny

I'm running Quarkus 2.7.0.CR1 with this code:

```
 return httpRequest.sendBuffer(createBuffer())
                   .onSubscription()
                       .invoke(() -> metricsRecorder.start(METRICS_NAME))
                   .onFailure()
                       .recoverWithUni(failure -> fetchWithOtherCredentials())
                   ...
```

`onFailure()` triggers if port in URL is not responding at all. But when returning HTTP 500 from WireMock this code just throws `WebApplicationException` with status 500 without triggering `onFailure()`. This is the exception that triggers `onFailure()`:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8085
```

`AnnotatedConnectException` seems to be checked exception but [in this example](https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-failure-handling/) `IllegalArgumentException` is used which is `RuntimeException` like `WebApplicationException`.

I thought `onFailure()` should trigger on any exception. Any ideas what is going on? I have tested with `@QuarkusTest` and also by running Quarkus locally with `mvn compile quarkus:dev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpRequest.sendBuffer()` returns a `Uni<HttpResponse<T>>`. When the server responds with status `500`, the Web Client does not emit a failure, it emits an `HttpResponse` with status code `500`.

You should inspect the response, like this:

```
Uni<HttpResponse> uni = httpRequest
    .sendBuffer(createBuffer())
    .onItem().transformToUni(res -> {
        if (res.statusCode() == 200 && res.getHeader("content-type").equals("application/json")) {
          // Do something with JSON body and return new Uni
        } else {
          // Generate failure as Uni
        }
    });
```

Another option is to use response [predicates](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bindings/2.18.1/apidocs/io/vertx/mutiny/ext/web/client/predicate/ResponsePredicate.html):

```
Uni<HttpResponse> uni = httpRequest
    .expect(ResponsePredicate.SC_SUCCESS)
    .expect(ResponsePredicate.JSON)
    .sendBuffer(createBuffer());
```

In this case, the returned `Uni<HttpResponse>` is successful only when the response has status code `200` and a JSON body, otherwise it is failed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using the `expect`, no other changes to code needed.